# Error while downloading features on qr-code generated using angularx-qrcode?

Tags: javascript, angular, qr-code

I used angularx-qrcode to generate a qrcode where it populates data from qrInfo. However I am getting this error:

*ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'qrcElement')*
The code on *qr-code-generate.component.html* looks like:

```
<qrcode *ngIf="qrInfo" cssClass="coolQRCode" #qrcode [qrdata]="qrInfo" [width]="256" elementType="img" [errorCorrectionLevel]="'M'"></qrcode><a [href]="link" download><button class="btn btn-block (click)="downloadQRCode()">Download QRCode</button></a>
```

Whereas the code on the controller *qr-code-generate.component.ts* looks:

```
link: string;
 @ViewChild('qrcode', { static: true }) qrcode: QRCodeComponent;

  qrInfo : any;
```

Back to the *.component.ts file we handle the downloadQRCode() function as follows:

```
downloadQRCode() {this.link = this.qrcode.qrcElement.nativeElement.firstChild.src}
```

I can not download the img using the reference to the qrcode element we can access it's firstChild. And when I remove *ngIf="qrInfo" from ***.component.html I am receiving an error

```
angularx-qrcode.mjs:165 [angularx-qrcode] Error generating QR Code: angularx-qrcode] Field `qrdata` is empty, set allowEmptyString="true"' to overwrite this behaviour.
```

Comment: Your ViewChild is not able  to 'pick' the `QRCodeComponent` instance.
Try with `@ViewChild('qrcode', { static: false }) qrcode: QRCodeComponent`
Also, make sure that your `<qrcode></qrcode>` is being rendered. According to your second attempt, `qrdata`seems to be falsy.

Comment: Problem solved... Thanks :) – @guzmanoj

Answer (score 0):

guzmanoj already helped out with the original issue, just as a future reference for other users, the lib angularx-qrcode has an issue where we track solutions how to [download a qrcode](https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode/issues/168)

I think I should implement the download feature in the [demo app](https://cordobo.github.io/angularx-qrcode/)

HTH